# Right-to-left direction for Ext.NET TextField

Tags: right-to-left, ext.net

I need to align the **`Ext:TextField`** control along with its `FieldLabel` attribute, as right-to-left direction. 
By setting `LabelAlign` to right and `body dir="rtl"`, I can only align all the control to the right.
And I get this format displayed:

> ---------Label:-|||||||TextField||||||||||

But how can I have the following format?

> |||||||TextField||||||||||---------:Label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FieldLabel` will not work for **rtl** text fields. The only solution found is to enclose a Label and a Text Field inside table cells, aligned in a table row, with `dir="rtl"` set to the table or container, like the following.

```
<table dir="rtl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ext:Label ID="Label1" Text="Sample Label" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <ext:textfield ID="Text1" Text="Sample Text" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is possible as there is no real need for such options.

I would suggest that you leave the Label of the text field blank and that you insert an label to the end...

Example:

```
<ext:textfield ID="Text1" Text="I start on the left" runat="server" />
<ext:label ID="Label1" Text="I am a label starting on the left staying on the right" StyleSpec="float: left;" />
```

It should work like this!